# How does return value work in java methods

Tags: java

I made this code to learn my self about how return works in java

```
public class test {

    public int sumDouble(int a, int b) {

        int k = (a + b);
        if (a == b) {
            k = k * 2;

        } else {
            k = (a + b);
        }

        return k;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter your number");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();

        test t = new test();
        t.sumDouble(a, b);

    }
}
```

I want to use the `return k` to print out the value of summation
How can use the `return k` to print out the sum value?
I tried to write        `System.out.println(t.k);` in the main method but it did not work ..

thanks

Comment: `sumDouble` is a method that returns a value. When doing `t.sumDouble(a, b);` you are ignoring this value. You should store this value inside a local variable: `int result = t.sumDouble(a, b)` and then print that `result`. I suggest you go through the Java tutorials for more info https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing to keep in mind here is that `k` is a local variable in the `sumDouble` method, so you can't refer to it elsewhere.

You can take the value returned by `sumDouble` and use it in your main method, however.

For instance, you can create a variable in `main` and assign its value to be the *value that is returned* from `sumDouble`, and you could print *that* variable, since it's in scope:

```
// at runtime, this will evaluate "t.sumDouble(a, b)" 
// and assign the value that it returns to the variable "sum"
int sum = t.sumDouble(a, b);
System.out.println(sum);
```

You could even skip the local variable and use the method call directly:

```
System.out.println(t.sumDouble(a, b));
```

Comment: I think having a separate intermediate local variable would be easier to understand (IMO).

Comment: @Tunaki Ok, I've rewritten it to try to be more clear.